# Batch with command with part of text list

Tags: batch-file, text

I have a text list with file name saved:

Path my text list: (Warning contains space)

```
D:\Programmi Installati\Software Portable\data\list.csv
```

This text list contains rows like this example:

```
FILE-1.OVPN
FILE-2.OVPN
FILE-3.OVPN
FILE-4.OVPN
FILE-5.OVPN
FILE-6.OVPN
FILE-LAST.OVPN
```

In the batch files I need to add this option in my command

> start /low /max "" "D:\Programmi Installati\Openvpn
>   Portable\OpenVPNPortable.exe" --connect FILE-1.OVPN --connect
>   FILE-2.OVPN --connect FILE-3.OVPN --connect FILE-4.OVPN --connect
>   FILE-5.OVPN --connect FILE-6.OVPN --connect FILE-LAST.OVPN

In my command i need to add --connect with the content of every row (from content row1 to content of raw last)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq" %%i in ("D:\Programmi Installati\Software Portable\data\list.csv") do (
 set params=!params! --connect %%i
)
echo %params% 
start /low /max "" "D:\Programmi Installati\Openvpn Portable\OpenVPNPortable.exe" %params%
```